# How to convert the bytes to the manual output when i read a PE file

Tags: python-3.x, byte, decode

My code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- #

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        f = open("test.dll", 'rb')
        context = f.read()
        f.close()
        print(context)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

The output are bytes like this when I use python3:

> b'b\'MZ\x90\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xb8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x1f\xba\x0e\x00\xb4\t\xcd!\xb8\x01L\xcd!This
>   program cannot be run in DOS mode.\r\r\n$\x00\x00\x00\x00

The output like this what I want when I use python2:

> MZ?         ?       @                                   ?   ?
>   ???L?This program cannot be run in DOS mode.
>
> $       2!跪v@住v@住v@住8B@住8^@住8T‰@住8D

How can I get the output like python2 with python3?

PS:
I try to decode the output like this:

```
context = f.read().decode("utf-8")
```

But there is a error like this:

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 2: invalid start byte

The other decode type has the same error.

How can I get the right output? thanks a lot.

Comment: tried `decode("utf-8",errors="ignore")` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh I'm sorry
I have got the method:

code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- #

if __name__ == "__main__":
     try:
        f = open("test.dll", 'rb')
        context = f.read().decode("utf-8", 'ignore')
        f.close()
        print(context)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

**Use the 'ignore' param**

Here is the truth:[enter link description here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/unicode.html)